# App not visible on Google Play for QHD LG G3?

Tags: android

I have a number of users complaining about our app not being visible on Google play on LG G3 device. Here is an excerpt from app's manifest file. Is there a screen resolution/density that I missed. Quick help highly appreciated.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<compatible-screens>

    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="large" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="213"
        android:screenSize="large" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple: get rid of `<compatible-screens>`.

Your objective, based on the range of values that you have there, appears to be to support all screen sizes and densities. In that case, **you do not need or want the `<compatible-screens>` element in your manifest**.

Quoting [the documentation for `<compatible-screens>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html):

> **Caution**: Normally, you should not use this manifest element. Using this element can dramatically reduce the potential user base for your application, by not allowing users to install your application if they have a device with a screen configuration that you have not listed. You should use it only as a last resort, when the application absolutely does not work with specific screen configurations. Instead of using this element, you should follow the guide to Supporting Multiple Screens to provide scalable support for multiple screens using alternative layouts and bitmaps for different screen sizes and densities.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your feedback. I did not have that XML element before, but added it later just to support Nexus 7. Are you sure if I remove this element all devices including tablets will get supported? Do I need to add anything extra to the following to support Nexus 7: <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

Comment: @user2733554: You do not need that element to support the Nexus 7.

Answer (score 2):

LG G3 have new one density category : xxxhdpi ( 640 ). You need to support it.

For this moment xxxhdpi value is not avaialable in SDK, but you can set the value like a number :

```
<compatible-screens>
<screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="small"/>
<screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="normal"/>
<screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="large"/>
<screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="xlarge"/>
</compatible-screens>
```